# iPhone - building a linear workflow with viewControllers

Tags: iphone, ios

I have this app that will have a single flow, something like a wizard, basically composed of 4 view controllers. Lets call them A, B, C and D.

Application starts showing A. From A, the user can go to B. From B the user can go to C or back to B. From D the user can go back to C or finish doing something and go back to A.

Something like:

```
A <-> B <-> C <-> D
^                 | 
┕━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┙
```

My point is this:

If I start on A, present B, present C, present D, all these A, B and C will be on the stack, so I can pop and go back to the last one, but when I am in D, in my head, the correct way to go to A, would be to pop D, C and B from the stack. How can I go from D to A, getting rid of everything that is on the stack?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line may be what you're after:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Apple's [UINavigationController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has excellent illustrations and examples for doing more exotic things (like jumping from D to B).

Answer (score 1):

You can use UINavigationControllers `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`, here is a reference [UINavigationController Class Ref](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

An `UINavigationController` could be a valid solution. By means of this component you have this type of linear workflow for free.

See Apple's documentation. [UINavigationController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)